# How to use forEach to alter an array

Tags: javascript, foreach

What code is required to instruct `forEach()` to make a permanent change to an array?

For example in the following simple code I add the phrase, "this is my " to each item in the array. According to the console log the changes were made.  But when I run the console again on the main timeline the changes weren't permanently saved to the array.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't see it.

```js
var myArray = [];

myArray.push("dog");
myArray.push("cat");
myArray.push("mouse");

console.log(myArray);

myArray.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item) {
    item = "this is my " +item;
    console.log(item);
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> forEach() does not mutate the array on which it is called (although
>   callback, if invoked, may do so).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Go with `Map`:

```js
var myArray = [];

myArray.push("dog");
myArray.push("cat");
myArray.push("mouse");

const myArrayChanged = myArray.map(myFunction);

function myFunction(item) {
    return "this is my " + item;
}

console.log(myArray);
console.log(myArrayChanged);
```

But, properly answering your question about how to do it using `forEach`, here it goes:

```js
var myArray = [];

myArray.push("dog");
myArray.push("cat");
myArray.push("mouse");

console.log(myArray);

myArray.forEach(myFunction);
function myFunction(item, i, arr) {
    return arr[i] = "this is my " + item;
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: I just googled and you are right `.map` is the ideal solution for what I was doing.  Thanks for the `forEach` example that gives me a lot to think about.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the `forEach` callback signature also includes the original array: `myFunction(item, index, array)` so you can call it without needing to reference an outside variable: `array[index] = 'this is my` + item` This makes it easier to reuse the callback with other arrays.

Comment: @MarkM @Diego Zoracky, is there a reference that lists the default arguments for methods like `forEach`?  I had no idea that `(item, index, array)` were automatically passed and that is super useful info.

Comment: @DR01D Mozilla has a good JavaScript reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @DR01D go with MDN when looking for references on JavaScript. e.g.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach